# Spring autowired user

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, autowired

I have an authentication service, and a module for the clients, which can be included to retrieve the authenticated user and verify the token.

What I want to achieve is to be able to do this:
`@Autowired MyUser user` to retrieve the correct user (request scope).

What I've done:

In the separate module that the clients can include:

```
@Configuration
public class MyUserHolder {
    @Bean
    @Scope(value="request", proxyMode= ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    public MyUser getMyUser() {
        return (MyUser) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    }
}
```

And in the client:

```
@Autowired MyUser user
```

There are no annotations on the MyUser class (is this correct?)

The error I get is:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No qualifying bean of type [...MyUser] found for dependency [...MyUser]:
expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.
```

I'm not sure if the problem comes from the fact that the object and annotations are in another module (included jar), or if the annotations are just incomplete... It feels like that MyUserHolder is not correctly available in the spring-context

Comment: Make sure your application is scanning (component scan) MyUserHolder class before auto-wiring MyUser in client.

Comment: Silly me, that solved everything :) If you'll post it as an answer, i'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally this issue occurs when Spring can't find bean to autowire, which means before autowiring, a respective bean needs to be created.
By making sure that application is scanning (component scan) MyUserHolder class before auto-wiring MyUser in client will resolve such issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.org.package1,com.org.package2" />
```

Make sure package includes the class in which bean not found exception occurs. You can use multiple package scan by separating it with `comma (,)

Spring will check automatically registered bean (`annotations`)inside the package defined in `component scan`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get current user anywhere you want, I would recommend my approach.
I'v created UserUtil class.
you get null when user is not authenticated.

```
public static YourUserPrincipalDto getCurrentUser(){
    try {
        return (YourUserPrincipalDto) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```